# How to get phone call ended notification after application is closed for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications, phone-call

In an iPhone app every time I end the phone call I want to ask user for yes/no type question & if 'Yes' is clicked the launch my application. I know I can get notifications for call end using CTTelephone but my question here is that is it possible to get the notifications even after my application is closed. If I run my application in background then there are chances that system closes it on low memory. Moreover apple doesn't support for continuos background application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not get notification if your app is close. Since you app does not fall in one of the background modes you will not be able to run the app in the background.

In short, the functionality you want is not possible with the official Apple SDK and guidelines.

Comment: Ok. What thoughts on background app? Will it keep the app in background?

Comment: If your app is either an AudioPlayer, VOIP or GPS track (ex. navigation) they Apple will allows your app to run in the background. But since your app does not wall in one of these categories you will not be able to run you app in background.